# Windows 10 scaling keeps changing

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution, scaling

During a typical day I move from my desk to meeting rooms and back several times a day. Every time I dock or un-dock the scaling of apps will change and the fonts and windows will become large. If I go into display settings the scaling will show as 100% although everything looks like it is set to 125%. I can resolve it by setting it to 125% and then back to 100%. This is annoying and sometimes causes long delays and apps to crash. It is also odd because all of my displays are Full HD 1920x1080 and I have always go them set at 100% scaling. I suspect the reason it does this is because the default scaling of the laptop monitor is 125% for a new windows install. I have set the scaling of all monitors to 100% more times than I can remember. When I do the change from 100 to 125 to 100 this mostly resolves the issue but some apps don't respond and keep the large settings making it difficult to work. Anyone have this issue?

Specs are:
Laptop screen: 15" 1920x1080
External screens: 2 x 24" 1920x1080

Answer (score 2):

I have something similar to you; 3x 1920x1080 with 2x 24" and 1x 14" and I had the same symptoms.

The only way I managed to sort it was to use a custom font scaling size, instructions below:

1. Open Control Panel > Display
2. Under 'Change size of items' there is a paragraph of text with 'set a custom scaling level' as a hyperlink; click through to that
3. I manually set a value of 120%, and the issue went away for me

Comment: This problem went away after a while so I suspect it was just a driver bug or windows bug